# Return JavaScript(). 4 good actions - 1 evil action !

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

The bad 'return JavaScript' goes like this:

1. This is the action link that gets selected.

   ```
   Ajax.ActionLink("Sign Out", "LogOff", "Account", new AjaxOptions { })
   ```
2. This is the action.

   ```
   public ActionResult LogOff()   
   {      
       FormsAuth.SignOut();   
       return JavaScript("ClearDisplayName()");  
   }
   ```
3. The JavaScript is never called !

Additioinal Info:

All javascript functions are all in the .js file.

Four other actions, in the same file, do their `return JavaScript(...)` successfully.

I tested the four working actions by doing a `return JavaScript("ClearDisplayName()")` and 
they all call `ClearDisplayName()` successfully.

I tested the failing action by doing a `return JavaScript("OtherKnownWorkingJava()")` with no luck.

Any idea's for this weird behavior ?

I noticed that all the successful actions pass through a View first.
The troubled action does not, it comes directly from an ActionLink.

Comment: What is the server-side technology? Please update the tags correctly.

Comment: Did you check the case and scope?

Comment: This looks like ASP.NET MVC v1.

Comment: The LogOff Action is directly from the sample MVC project in VS.
Instead of returning to an action I'm returning JavaScript(...)

        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            FormsAuth.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

Answer (score 1):

After throwing some mud against this problem here's how I was able to call
'return JavaScript("ClearDisplayName")'.

Instead of trying to do 'return JavaScript("ClearDisplayName") from the **LogOff**
action, I redirected to another action, **LogOffA**, and did a 'return JavaScript("ClearDisplayName") there, and it worked !!

```
    public ActionResult LogOffA()
    {
        return JavaScript("ClearDisplayName()");
    }

    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuth.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("LogOffA", "Account");
        //return JavaScript("ClearDisplayName()");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `FormsAuth` properly defined? Shouldn't that be `FormsAuthentication`?

Answer (score 0):

Are other actions also invoked by Ajax.ActionLink?

I doubt it Ajax.ActionLink will process the JavaScript return. If so, you either process the result yourself (using eval(response)), or avoid using Ajax.ActionLink, or return view instead that has
$(document).ready(function(){<%=ViewData["jsfunc"]%>};);
- this will most likely be processed, though you'll need jQuery.